# Which ports need to be allowed through firewall to seed torrent using transmission-cli on headless server?

Tags: port, bittorrent, torrent-tracker

Self-hosting my own tracker using [bittorrent-tracker](https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker).

Opened `UDP` port `6969` on tracker and seed servers.

What else needs to be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

For both the tracker as well as the torrent client the answer is the same:

The ports you configured.

Trackers traditionally listen on *TCP* port 6969. They could be listening on other ports (both TCP and UDP), too. It depends on the setup.

BitTorrent technically has well-known ports (*TCP* 6881-6889). The DHT protocol may use different UDP ports. The uTP protocol may use different UDP ports. In practice, it again depends on the configuration.

If you are behind a NAT gateway of any kind, you also need port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Do clients punch through NAT?

Comment: You shouldn’t count on it.

Comment: I enabled port forwarding on Mullvad. Transmission client on macOS sees tracker (which lists one seeder, me, running transmission-cli on Linux). Problem is Transmission client on macOS still cannot connect to Linux client. Would you happen to know what is going on?

Comment: No, sorry. You better ask a new question about that where you describe your network structure in greater detail.